# How to open Default Email Application in PHP

Tags: php, email, lotus-notes, outlook-2010

Hi Guys I am just this curious, I wonder if PHP can do this stuff:
I have an anchor tag that says "send email to admin".

What I want to do is to open a default email client such ms outlook or lotus and automatically create an empty mail message.

I only want PHP to do it. Is it possible?

If it may, how should I do it?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response guys ! It's funny to think how fast I get answers from this problem when no one is answering my pending jChartFX issues. haha

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML - the browser will handle it.

`<a href="mailto:test@example.com">Click me</a>`

Answer (score 2):

PHP only runs on the webserver, it has no access to the programs on a client-computer.

I think you want to use mailto

```
<a href="mailto:fritz.eierschale@example.org">Fritz Eierschale, fritz.eierschale@example.org</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is possible, though not directly by means pf php:

If I got you right, then you want to offer sending such an email on a web page created by means of php. If so, then all you have to do is use a "mailto" reference. The clients environment will decide what application to open to use that link:

```
<a href="mailto:admin@some.page.org">Send email to admin</a>
```

Note however that this only works, if there is a local email client installed and configured at all on the client side. More and more users use web based email applications instead of a local client, with all the disadvantages. In such case the clients system will popup an error about no suitable application available...

Comment: So how could I select a specific mail application (for example I only want it to happen using lotus?)

Comment: @Kentot - you can't really

Comment: You can't, and that for good reasons. It is not up to a web page implementation (so server side logic), what happens on the client side. That would be a huge break of privacy. and frankly: you don't want to. Leave it to the client side user to decide what email application he/she wants to use. It is non of your business.